# Why is there a symlink from /usr/local/bin/ to /usr/sbin?

Tags: software-installation, sudo, root, symbolic-link, ubuntu-mate

What is the purpose of this symlink?

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/snort /usr/sbin/snort
```

It was a part of the installation process for snort. Now I do not know if it is because it is supposed to be launched as deamon every time or because it has to be launched with `sudo` in general?

Comment: Probably to fix this bug https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=388221

Comment: Thanks, this is the only one explanation that i have got

Comment: Which installation process? `sudo apt-get install snort` doesn't create such a symlink.

Comment: i have installed snort from source packages not from repository

Answer (score 1):

The likely purpose of this symbolic link is to add the `snort` command to a directory included in the default list of directories that are scanned for commands by most shell interpreters. This allows users to invoke `snort` without the need to specify its full path `/usr/local/bin/snort` or to adjust the value of the `PATH` shell variable (which is used to determine the list of directories scanned for commands).

You can inspect the current value of the `PATH` variable with

```
echo "$PATH"
```